# Correct usage of participial phrase

Tags: grammar, participial

I have trouble with an SAT grammar question:

1. The delegates coming this far, they did not want to return without accomplishing something.

I got it down to 2 choices:

- (B) Coming this far, the delegates felt they
- (C) Having come this far, the delegates

The correct answer is (C); however, I do not understand the differences between (B) and (C).

Comment: "Coming this far" is (I believe) present-tense.  "Having come this far" is past tense, and therefore more consistent with the past-tense that "the delegates felt" is in. Tense is not my strong suit, but I believe this is correct.

Comment: This is less an answer and more an SAT technique, but try rewriting them as "The delegates, having come this far,..." or "The delegates, coming this far,..."  That should make it clear which is the correct choice.

Comment: It seems to me this is really a question about the whims of your SAT examiners than a question about actual English. In terms of the language at large, either (B) or (C) is grammatical, and the choice would depend on the exact nuance of what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Amory But even in your re-written versions, both versions are grammatical. I'm not sure what this "technique" really helps with...

Comment: @NeilCoffey I don't think the first example is grammatical.  What do you base this claim on?  I think that tense agreement alone would militate against B being correct.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this question would be better asked on [ell.se]

Comment: I am assuming that the participle phrase was underlined as was _they_ in the stem of the original question.  They (SAT writers) are testing tense agreement and sequence.  (C) is the correct answer because "having come" and and "did . . . want" are consistent tenses.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist Native speaker intuition and observation of general patterns of the language used by other native speakers. (Now, that's far from infallible, but it's a common means of judging grammaticality, and no less fallible means is being proposed.)

Comment: @MichaelOwenSartin But nothing objectively makes them "consistent" really. They're clearly *different*, so what does that "consistency" mean? What is your judge of "consistency" that means that this combination is "good", while the combination in (B) is "bad", and what objectively makes that the "right" judgement? And in any case, so what -- why do you suppose that the language owes you some guarantee that "tenses shall be consistent"? Observation clearly shows that this isn't the case: all sorts of combinations of tenses are readily used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant distinction between the two participial adjuncts is in the specification of aspect. *Having come this far...* is marked for **perfect** aspect. The perfect is used to indicate an event having occurred prior to some reference time (whether this reference time is at the time of speaking, or at some focal point in the past or future) as having continuing relevance. Perfect aspect is marked in English with the auxiliary verb *have*.

The other adjunct, *Coming this far...*, is not marked for aspect, so there is no grammatical indication as to whether the event is complete, ongoing, or yet to be undertaken. The default interpretation is that the event is ongoing when you use present participle adjunct without perfect marking.

In deciding which sentence is best you need to consider the functional motivation in choosing to use perfect aspect versus leaving the aspect unspecified. If you want your adjunct to point out a past event with continuing relevance to the main event you are describing, the perfect aspect is preferred. If you want to refer to an event, but its temporal relation to the main event you are describing is not too important, then you don't use the perfect.

The first choice is preferred because the fact that the delegates have already "come far" is relevant to their feeling of wanting to accomplish at least something. The aspectually unmarked adjunct would be preferable in the case where the main event was somehow framed by the event depicted in the adjunct. e.g.,

> Coming this far, the delegates made many friendships and alliances amongst themselves.

Answer (score 0):

"The delegates coming this far" is a noun phrase. The error is exactly the same as if you said "John, he didn't want to go home."